# Delete DOM elements throught loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a loop which is reponsible to delete DOM elements (one or severals lines into an HTML table) :

```
<tr class="entireLine><input type="checkbox"></tr>
<tr class="entireLine><input type="checkbox" checked></tr>
<tr class="entireLine><input type="checkbox" checked></tr>
```

JS

```
for (var i=0; i<$(".entireLine").length; i++){
        // Get the current line of the table
        var currentLine = $(".entireLine")[i];
        // Get the checkbox in the DOM element
        var checkbox = $(currentLine).find("input[type=checkbox]");
        // Check the state of the checkbox. If checked, remove the line. 
        if ( $(checkbox).is(":checked") ) {
            $(currentLine).remove();
        }
    }
```

This code works fine only when there is one line selected. From 2 lines selected, the second line is not deleted because the index (i) is not good after the first remove.

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: `$(".entireLine").length` does change during your iteration, and so does `$(".entireLine")` on which you are accessing `[i]`. Just don't repeat the DOM selection and it'll work fine.

Comment: It's invalid markup to put an `<input>` directly inside a `<tr>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just find tr with checked checkboxes

```
$(".entireLine").has('input[type=checkbox]:checked').remove()
```

In your loop the problem is the expression `$(".entireLine").length` is evaluated in each iteration, it will reduce the length if item was removed in the previous iteration but the value of `i` is not reduced so there will be some leftout items

- [.has()](https://api.jquery.com/has/)
- [:checked](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Use a jquery each:

```
$(".entireLine").each(function( index ) {
    if ($(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked")) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

And correct your HTML, it's not `<tr class="entireLine>` but `<tr class="entireLine">` (You forget the closing `"`)

Answer (score 0):

Reverse your thinking - instead of looping through all the rows to find selected items, find the selected items then remove their rows:

```
$(":checkbox:selected").each(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this, instead of doing the for loop. This will find all the checkboxes, and do a $.each and if they are checked, it will remove them. I put checkboxes in its own var for debugging purposes.

```
var checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]'); 

checkboxes.each(function(){
        var $checkbox = $(this); 
        if ( $checkbox.is(":checked") ) {
            $checkbox.remove();
        }
})
```